# I have a problem with how to forward API request in Jersey

Tags: java, api, jersey, jax-rs

I am new to REST API. I want to forward the request to another API endpoint when user calling one API. 
I try to implement it by the following code but it doesn't work.

```
@Path("/API/v1/NEW/keys")

public class KmsAuditing {

private Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

@GET

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

  public Response getResult() {

    WebTarget MyResponse = client.target("/API/v1/keys");

   return  Response.ok(MyResponse).build();

}
@PreDestroy

public void destroy(){

this.client.close();
   }
}
```

when I call "/API/v1/NEW/keys", this request will forward to "/API/v1/keys". And these two APIs on the same server. Can anyone help me to figure this out? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the endpoint is on the same server, the client still expects *full* URL. If you don't want to use a static URL, you can get the base path from the `UriInfo` that you can inject into your resource method.

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getResult(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
   // you might need to play around with this. I'm not sure exactly
   // the base will be. Do some debugging if needed.
   URI uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
           .path("/API/v1/keys")
           .build();
   WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
   Response response = target.request().get();
   ...
}
```

Also notice that you can't just return the `Response`. You need to get whatever the response it. The most generic way you can do this is to read it as an `InputStream` and just return that. But you should also check the status of the client request to make sure that it was a successful request. Maybe something like

```java
if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
    return Response.ok(response.readEntity(InputStream.class)).build();
} else {
    return Response.serverError().build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I also have a question. I  use a jersey filter to log the request and response information. How can I get the information together and make it as a JSON data?